# in httpd.conf file www.domain2.com resolves to www.domain1.com instead

Tags: linux, wordpress, amazon-web-services, apache, httpd.conf

I am using aws amazon linux 2 t3.medium servers
I have installed httpd (not apache2) for configuring 2 wordpress websites
Here's how my .conf file looks for 2 domains says domain1.com and domain2.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAlias www.domain1.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/domain1/"
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain1.com:443
    ServerAlias www.domain1.com:443
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain1/

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/cert
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain2.com
    ServerAlias www.domain2.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/domain2/"
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain2.com:443
    ServerAlias www.domain2.com:443
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain2/

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/cert
</VirtualHost>
```

**The issue I am facing is that**
domain1.com is resolving correctly
[www.domain1.com](http://www.domain1.com) is resolving correctly
domain2.com is resolving correctly
but [www.domain2.com](http://www.domain2.com) is resolving to domain1.com

What could be the issue?

I want help with proper configuration so that [www.domain2.com](http://www.domain2.com) should not resolve to domain1.com

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Domain Name hosting in Route53 or any other DNS provider where you have put your records for domains.

Kindly note that httpd is the Apache service which is used in Amazon Linux 2, CentOS, RHEL OSes.

Put DNS records as below -

```
A record - domain1.com <public_ip_of_EC2>
CNAME record - www.domain1.com domain1.com
A record - domain2.com <public_ip_of_EC2>
CNAME record - www.domain2.com domain2.com
```

Hope this will solve the issue.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, I have done this as well. What happens is if I shift domain2 config above domain1 config then www.domain1.com will redirect to domain2.com. It's quite weird what's happening in config files.

Comment: Sorry, your reply is not clear to me. Can you please describe your problem in detail.